# convert mysql_connect to cfquery

Tags: php, mysql, cfml

What would be the equivalent of the code below in coldfusion. I'm able to connect to database with php but having trouble with properly setting cfquery tag

```
mysql_connect("your.hostaddress.com", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("Database_Name") or die(mysql_error()); 
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM friends") 
or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: You need to create a datasource in the CF Administrator first. Then you can use it in your query The online docs have instructions on [creating datasources](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Admin/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf3639b1-7ffc.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf3639b1-7ffb) - though sadly no screen shots like in [this entry](http://www.pukkared.com/2010/03/setting-up-a-datasource-in-coldfusion-administrator/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll have to setup the database information as a datasource in the ColdFusion Administrator.

```
<cftry>
    <cfquery name="data" datasource="myCFDataSourceThatISetupInTheCFAdmin" username="username" password="secret">
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            friends
    </cfquery>

    <cfcatch type="database">
        <!--- Do some Error Stuff here if you want, like throw a database error --->
    </cfcatch>
</cftry>
<cfdump var="#data#">

<cfoutput query="data">
    #column1name# #column2name#<hr>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Though if you aren't going to do anything about it, you can skip the try catch and let it fail, like the "or die" would.

Comment: Sorry wasn't sure what the "die" did in PHP so I tried to emulate some action that would gracefully catch a failed database call.

Answer (score 1):

It's a while since I've done anything with ColdFusion, but first you need to set up a datasource in the control panel pointing at your database with the correct credentials. We'll assume you called it `fred`. Then you can address it by name:

```
<cfquery name="data" datasource="fred">
SELECT * FROM friends
</cfquery>

<cfoutput query="data">
<div>Name: #name#; email: #email#</div>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: You mean "fibble", not fred :)

Comment: Fyi - datasource name difference fixed

Comment: I like it the other way around. "A datasource named Fred" sounds like a country western song :)